# Is there a summary of time spent on the different parts in a Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins

After a Jenkins build, I would need a way to see the times spent on the different parts of the Jenkins build. Is that possible? With different parts I mean cleaning the workspace, doing a CVS/Git update, copying artifacts, executing ant script, ...

Comment: In the Console Output, I can't see any TimeStamps... I thought there might be a plugin showing a summary of times spent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin in jenkins named `Timestamper`. After installing this plugin, Enable timestamps within the `Build Environment` section of the build's configuration page.

[image]

Comment: This is the plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper - you beat me to the answer

Comment: Exactly.. I was using this, so I knew it straight away. 1 up-vote from my side to your comment.. ;)